# Java animation does not refresh properly and uses too much CPU

Tags: java, swing, animation, awt, graphics2d

I have a problem with a simple Java game I am creating right now. I want a dot (a car) to be movable across the game screen, but instead of this all I can see on the screen is the long "snake" created by the dot moved by me:

[image: Screenshot]

Other problem is that activity manager on my Mac shows that the game uses huge amount of CPU power - my laptop gets very hot very fast. I suspect that there is something wrong with my game loop, but since now I haven't found any solution:

BoardPanel.java:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {
    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;


    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;

    private BufferedImage image;
    private Graphics2D g;

    private int FPS = 30;
    private int targetTime = 1000/FPS;

    private Map map;
    private Car car;

    public BoardPanel() {
        super();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        if(thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void run() {
        init();

        long startTime;
        long reTime;
        long waitTime;

        while (running) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            update();
            render();
            draw();

            reTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            waitTime = targetTime - reTime;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        running = true;
        image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

        map = new Map();
        car = new Car(map);
        car.setxpos(50);
        car.setypos(50);

    }

    private void update() {
        map.update();
        car.update();

    }

    private void render() {
        map.draw(g);
        car.draw(g);
    }

    private void draw() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent key) {

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        int code = key.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            car.setLeft(true);
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            car.setRight(true);
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            car.setUp(true);
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            car.setDown(true);
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent key) {
        int code = key.getKeyCode();

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            car.setLeft(false);
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            car.setRight(false);
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            car.setUp(false);
        }
        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            car.setDown(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Car.java

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Car {
    private double xpos;
    private double ypos;

    //private int xsize;
    //private int ysize;

    private boolean left;
    private boolean right;
    private boolean up;
    private boolean down;

    private Map map;

    public Car(Map m) {
        map = m;
    }

    public void setxpos(int i) {
        xpos = i;
    }

    public void setypos(int i) {
        ypos = i;
    }

    public void setLeft (boolean b) {
        left = b;
    }

    public void setRight (boolean b) {
        right = b;
    }

    public void setUp (boolean b) {
        up = b;
    }

    public void setDown (boolean b) {
        down = b;
    }

    public void update() {
        if(left) {
            xpos--;
        }

        if(right) {
            xpos++;
        }
        if(up) {
            ypos--;
        }
        if(down) {
            ypos++;
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        int mx = map.getx();
        int my = map.gety();

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval((int)(mx+xpos-20/2), (int)(my+ypos-20/2), 20, 20);
    }
}
```

Map.java (I haven't created map yet, right now only want the dot to move properly)

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Map {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public int getx() {
        return x;
    }

    public int gety() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setx(int i) {
        x = i;
    }

    public void sety(int i ) {
        y = i;
    }

    public void update() {

    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    }


}
```

RacerMain.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class RacerMain {
    public static void main (String[]args) {
        //MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        JFrame mf = new JFrame("Racer");
        mf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mf.setContentPane(new BoardPanel());;
        mf.pack();
        mf.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what camickr said: Be careful with your usage of the `Graphics`. A rule of thumb:

**Never call `getGraphics` on a Component!**

Additionally, you are never disposing the `Graphics` that you are fetching from the `BufferedImage`. You are instead disposing the `Graphics` that you obtained from the Component, which may be even worse than *fetching* it in the first place!

I wonder why you are overriding the `addNotify` method. You should not implement any functionality based on averriding this method....

So you should change the respecive parts of your `BoardPanel` class roughly as follows:

```
public class BoardPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable     {
    ...
    // private Graphics2D g; // Don't store this here

    public BoardPanel() {
        ...

        // Create the thread here instead of in the "addNotify" method!
        if(thread == null) {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
        addKeyListener(this);
    }


    public void run() {
        ...
        while (running) {
            ...
            //draw(); // Don't call this method
            repaint(); // Trigger a repaint instead!
        }
    }


    private void render() {
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();

        // Clear the background (see camickrs answer)
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight());

        try
        {
            map.draw(g);
            car.draw(g);
        }
        finally
        {
            g.dispose(); // Dispose the Graphics after it has been used
        }
    }

    /** Don't call "getGraphics" on a component!   
    private void draw() {
        Graphics g2 = getGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g2.dispose();
    }
    */

    // Override the paintComponent method instead:
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your draw() method you need to clear the BufferedImages background before your invoke the fillOval method. Something like:

```
g.setColor( Color.BLACK );
g.fillRect(...);
g.setColor( Color.BLUE );
g.fillOval(...);
```

Print out your "waitTime" to make sure you are waiting a reasonable time.